# Mouseover Mouseout with overlapping content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I mouseover the div with `class=background` (the little green square in the demo) I fade in the div with `class=hover` (displaying the grey and blue divs in the demo).

The grey partially overlaps the `.background` and I can move the mouse around inside it without triggering the `mouseout` on `.background`.

But..

If I move the mouse outside the grey div (to hover over the blue for example) then the `mouseout` on `.background` gets triggered.

How can I prevent this from happening so that as long as I am hovering over the newly displayed `.hover` div the `mouseout` on '.background' will not be triggered?

```js
$('.AddDiv').on('click', function() {
  var html = '<div class="container"><div class="background"></div><div class="hover"></div></div>';
  $('.Wrap').prepend(html);
});

$(".Wrap").on("mouseover", ".background", function() {
  $(this).next(".hover").fadeIn(500);
});

$(".Wrap").on("mouseout", ".hover", function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(200);
});
```

```css
.Wrap {
  width: 650px;
  height: 800px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.AddDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
.background {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 170px;
  top: 10px;
}
.content {
  width: 170px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}
.navigation {
  width: 190px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 5px;
}
.hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1001;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="hover">
      <div class="content"></div>
      <div class="navigation"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class=AddDiv>AddDiv</button>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please take a few moments and edit your question into something that we can understand, remember: we can *see* your code but we don't know the intent behind your code. And, currently, the text of your question is difficult to parse into a clear statement of what you want to happen.

Comment: I would like mouseover on green box and show div class="hover" and when I mouseout  from class="hover", class="hover" hide

Comment: Do you mean, that when mouse move over "content" and "navigation" inside of "hover", that all should not desappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`:

```
$('.AddDiv').on('click', function() {
    $('.Wrap').prepend($('<div class="container"><div class="background"></div><div class="hover"></div></div>'));
});

$(".Wrap").on("mouseover", ".background", function () {
    $(this).next(".hover").fadeIn(500);
});


$(".Wrap").on("mouseleave", ".hover", function () {
$(this).fadeOut(200);
});
```