# javascript add link on image hover > keep link active on link hover

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a link on an image when i'm hovering the image.
Currently my javascript is as follow:

```
// check elements mouse is hover
document.addEventListener("mouseover", addCropLink, true);
document.addEventListener("mouseout", removeCropLink, true);
// add link if element is image
function addCropLink(){
    var target = event.target;
    if (target instanceof HTMLImageElement){
        var cropLink = document.createElement("a");
        cropLink.setAttribute("class", "resizeMyPhoto");
        cropLink.setAttribute("id", "resizeMyPhoto");
        cropLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        cropLink.innerHTML += "Crop/Resize";
        cropLink.href = chrome.extension.getURL("index.html#");
        cropLink.href = cropLink.href + target.src;
        target.parentNode.style.position = "relative";
        target.parentNode.style.display = "inline-block";
        target.parentNode.insertBefore(cropLink, target.nextSibling);
    }
}

// remove link if element is image
function removeCropLink(){
    var target = event.target;
    if (target instanceof HTMLImageElement){
        var cropLink = document.getElementById("resizeMyPhoto");
        cropLink.parentNode.removeChild(cropLink);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when a user tries to click the link, he is doing mouseout from the image and the link is being removed.

Can some one suggest a solution?

**edited**
using mouseout / mouseleave did not solved the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mouseover Mouseout with overlapping content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574662/mouseover-mouseout-with-overlapping-content)

Comment: Sorry Yosef, changing:
document.addEventListener("mouseout", removeCropLink, true);
to:
document.addEventListener("mouseleave", removeCropLink, true);
Doesn't resolve this issue...
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

OK so I have changed my script so it won't run on mosueleave / mouse out at all.
i'm cecking on which element the mouse is over and if he is not on the image OR the link i created, i remove the link.
here is the full javascript with comments:

```
iconURL = chrome.extension.getURL("/icons/button-icon.png");
// check elements mouse is hover
document.addEventListener("mouseover", setLink, true);
// handles creating of the crop link
function setLink(){
var target = event.target;
if (target instanceof HTMLImageElement){
    // make sure no links are visible
    var cropLink = document.getElementById("resizeMyPhoto");
    if (cropLink !== null){
        cropLink.parentNode.removeChild(cropLink);
    }
    // create the link
    else{
        cropLink = document.createElement("a");
        cropLink.setAttribute("class", "resizeMyPhoto");
        cropLink.setAttribute("id", "resizeMyPhoto");
        cropLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        cropLink.innerHTML += "Crop/Resize";
        cropLink.href = chrome.extension.getURL("index.html#") + target.src;
        target.parentNode.style.position = "relative";
        target.parentNode.style.display = "inline-block";
        target.parentNode.insertBefore(cropLink, target.nextSibling);
    }
}
else{
    var cropLink = document.getElementById("resizeMyPhoto");
    // make sure mouse is not on link
    if(target == cropLink || cropLink == null){
        return;
    }
    // remove the link
    else{
        cropLink.parentNode.removeChild(cropLink);
    }
}
```

}

Hope this will help someone...